# iOS: Default IB popover transition does strange things

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, storyboard

I bumped into a strange issue where when a view controller is presented in a popover, the presenting view controllers `view` is not snapped to the bottom edge of it's superview, in that case the `window` itself.

AppDelegate code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "NavigationController", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateInitialViewController()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.backgroundColor = .yellow // Needed to detect the issue.
    self.window = window

    return true
}
```

Storyboard to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11762" systemVersion="16C67" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="4lt-Df-IeL">
    <device id="retina5_5" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11757"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Navigation Controller (locked)-->
        <scene sceneID="ryr-GW-wBz">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="NavigationController" definesPresentationContext="YES" id="4lt-Df-IeL" userLabel="Navigation Controller (locked)" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="gxR-oc-l6J"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="Py7-tH-kHP"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="865-DH-bRZ" userLabel="Background View">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="736"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <containerView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="535-Cq-y2B">
                                <rect key="frame" x="54" y="64" width="360" height="618"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="G7K-pY-ZSi" kind="embed" identifier="ContainerViewController" id="0Mw-mh-5NT"/>
                                </connections>
                            </containerView>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xLz-jb-9OM" userLabel="Left View">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="54" height="672"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bls-BC-WIu" userLabel="Left Stack View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="54" height="672"/>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Zbx-7u-5oe" userLabel="Hairline View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="53" y="0.0" width="1" height="672"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.43079092749999998" green="0.1140047376" blue="0.1180379456" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="1" id="kna-vk-GlF" customClass="OnePixelConstraint" customModule="segue_issue" customModuleProvider="target"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.627" green="0.114" blue="0.14099999999999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="54" id="2bA-Ap-aup"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bls-BC-WIu" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="xLz-jb-9OM" secondAttribute="leading" id="3sM-Bd-eEq"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Zbx-7u-5oe" secondAttribute="bottom" id="9PW-0y-kBv"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Zbx-7u-5oe" secondAttribute="trailing" id="RlN-G4-8iD"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="bls-BC-WIu" secondAttribute="trailing" id="anE-HT-oQp"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Zbx-7u-5oe" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="xLz-jb-9OM" secondAttribute="top" id="bxG-xS-wdV"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bls-BC-WIu" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="xLz-jb-9OM" secondAttribute="top" id="ds3-z5-Dpv"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="bls-BC-WIu" secondAttribute="bottom" id="f9r-FV-enN"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="V3o-XH-Xkn" userLabel="Bottom View">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="682" width="414" height="54"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fM3-hA-kGa" userLabel="Bottom Stack View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="54"/>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Gtr-bO-frP" userLabel="Hairline View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="1"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.43079092749999998" green="0.1140047376" blue="0.1180379456" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="1" id="K5f-m2-BpE" customClass="OnePixelConstraint" customModule="segue_issue" customModuleProvider="target"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.627" green="0.114" blue="0.14099999999999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Gtr-bO-frP" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" secondAttribute="leading" id="9fX-NI-RdG"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="fM3-hA-kGa" secondAttribute="bottom" id="KxS-jW-8Rh"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="fM3-hA-kGa" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" secondAttribute="top" id="VLk-U3-Dgt"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Gtr-bO-frP" secondAttribute="trailing" id="aDz-aj-8ah"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="fM3-hA-kGa" secondAttribute="trailing" id="bzw-Bv-nvH"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="54" id="ghd-qS-t3l"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Gtr-bO-frP" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" secondAttribute="top" id="nZz-Tn-i7X"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="fM3-hA-kGa" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" secondAttribute="leading" id="sxO-BS-rki"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <navigationBar contentMode="scaleToFill" translucent="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SAV-Rj-fPh">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="64"/>
                                <color key="barTintColor" red="0.627" green="0.114" blue="0.14099999999999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <textAttributes key="titleTextAttributes">
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                    <offsetWrapper key="textShadowOffset" horizontal="0.0" vertical="0.0"/>
                                </textAttributes>
                            </navigationBar>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NmK-Xz-xl3" userLabel="Navigation Bar Hairline">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="414" height="1"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.43079092750694548" green="0.11400473755687479" blue="0.11803794560598729" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="1" id="ENM-UW-O3D" customClass="OnePixelConstraint" customModule="segue_issue" customModuleProvider="target"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="alk-Uo-pMv">
                                <rect key="frame" x="192" y="0.0" width="46" height="30"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="G7K-pY-ZSi" kind="popoverPresentation" popoverAnchorView="alk-Uo-pMv" id="XuB-dB-CVh">
                                        <popoverArrowDirection key="popoverArrowDirection" up="YES" down="YES" left="YES" right="YES"/>
                                    </segue>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="535-Cq-y2B" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="xLz-jb-9OM" secondAttribute="trailing" id="0Ya-fi-fwL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="535-Cq-y2B" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="865-DH-bRZ" secondAttribute="trailing" id="2xc-7B-pd6"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" secondAttribute="trailing" id="4Qi-nQ-1b5"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="NmK-Xz-xl3" secondAttribute="trailing" id="4nX-tS-V49"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" secondAttribute="top" constant="54" id="8oE-54-0JN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="SAV-Rj-fPh" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="865-DH-bRZ" secondAttribute="top" id="DdA-dN-ucd"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="865-DH-bRZ" secondAttribute="leading" id="KzS-R2-JSi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="SAV-Rj-fPh" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="gxR-oc-l6J" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="44" id="Okf-F1-Bwv">
                                <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=regular" constant="64"/>
                            </constraint>
                            <constraint firstItem="NmK-Xz-xl3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="SAV-Rj-fPh" secondAttribute="bottom" id="Z7z-vD-Ypi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="SAV-Rj-fPh" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="865-DH-bRZ" secondAttribute="leading" id="ZYY-Wz-1eh"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="SAV-Rj-fPh" secondAttribute="trailing" id="ein-Qv-Vwc"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="xLz-jb-9OM" secondAttribute="bottom" id="fmP-cS-nYy"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NmK-Xz-xl3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="865-DH-bRZ" secondAttribute="leading" id="nYe-rf-Zht"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="xLz-jb-9OM" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="SAV-Rj-fPh" secondAttribute="bottom" id="tqI-Vx-dCH"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="xLz-jb-9OM" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-54" id="vuB-AY-U4j"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="V3o-XH-Xkn" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="535-Cq-y2B" secondAttribute="bottom" id="wCH-Rs-saK"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="535-Cq-y2B" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="SAV-Rj-fPh" secondAttribute="bottom" id="yeH-A6-JEo"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
                    <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics" statusBarStyle="lightContent"/>
                    <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
                    <size key="freeformSize" width="414" height="736"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="bpj-us-mEU" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="681" y="-398"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="O4R-kZ-Pdk">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ContainerViewController" id="G7K-pY-ZSi" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="ffW-Hu-TSB"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="0mf-BW-Ssn"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="x2i-Md-44j">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="360" height="618"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.94235802664974622" green="0.91986702625601058" blue="0.90890064764795653" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="B2f-Up-4gW" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1537.68115942029" y="-398.64130434782612"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <inferredMetricsTieBreakers>
        <segue reference="XuB-dB-CVh"/>
    </inferredMetricsTieBreakers>
    <color key="tintColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
</document>
```

Copy everything inside a new project, remove `main` as the main storyboard to launch.

1. Run the project on an iPhone X Plus simulator (or real device).
2. Click on the bottom to present a view controller.
   2.1. Enable slow motion (simulator only).
3. Rotate your device.

The issue I'm talking about is when the yellow `view` is visible (`window`). One rotation does layout the presenting view controller correctly, the other does begin in wrong state.

[image]

Is that a bug that my storyboard has or something from `UIKit`?

**Update:** The project uses latest iOS SDK and no deprecated APIs (as shown above 'almost everything is build with IB').

**Update 2:** I updated the original sentence to make it crystal clear that it's **not** a `UIPopoverController`.

Comment: `Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.`  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopovercontroller though not an answer I found this.

Comment: @souvickcse This is not a popover controller but a transition - that are two different worlds. ;) The transition is not exclusive for any devices, furthermore the iPhone X Plus has **rW cH** in landscape, which makes for example possible to use a UISplitViewController like on iPads, but that's not the point here. One more thing to note: There is no exception or any other sort of runtime errors. As described above it is a visual issue.

Comment: but you are using popover segue right?

Comment: @DevAndArtist This is not an issue but it's something which is visible while using transitions. Since, transitions are not device specific so I think you should not worry.

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 It is an unacceptable visual issue from my point of view which implies that my project cannot make use of the defaults. Either I have to reinvent the wheel here and build the same behavior from scratch, or this can be fixed in a future `UIKit` release. The *yellow* window view does the job right and resizes itself while rotating. However the popover transition is resizing my view before the transition occurs, so after the transition the view is in the right spot, but while transitioning it has a clearly visual issue.